# How To Load Rake Library In Python

Tags: python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7 and i get a error stating `Import Error - No module named RAKE`. Please advise how do i import Rake library?

I have tried RAKE-tutorial but no success.

Comment: have you installed rake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you downloaded it using pip?

```
pip install python-rake
```

And then in the code

```
import RAKE
```

Comment: when i type import rake in jupiter notebook it throws an error no module named rake.

Comment: i have downloaded using pip.

Comment: Good to hear! :)

Comment: I m getting the same error today when i try to import rake. Its already installed. Please advise.

Comment: Download it from here [link](https://pypi.python.org/packages/fa/20/6f19eb9f5024acf94b65c377256eedec35dd2113f6c4e3036614f56554ed/python-rake-1.0.7.tar.gz) extract it and put it in your folder with your other Python files and try again to import it.

Comment: It is already installed under the python folder but unable to import it.

Comment: in cmd prompt i get the confirmation stating python rake in c------ folder.

Comment: Yes it worked after reinstalling it. Thank you much.

Comment: from RAKE import Rake

Answer (score 4):

Using PIP

```
pip install rake-nltk
```

Or use can insyall directly from the repository

```
git clone https://github.com/csurfer/rake-nltk.git
python rake-nltk/setup.py install
```

How to Use it

```
from rake_nltk import Rake
```